# Where am I doing wrong with regular expression in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I want my `operator` variable matches a list of possible operators ("+", "-", "*", "/", "^") for exactly once, so I did

```
operator.matches(Pattern.quote("[+-*/^]??"))
```

It doesn't work. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Your problem appears to be at step 1 : use a regex to parse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Pattern.quote` would quote your whole input. It will not magically ignore your `[]??` and only look at things inside the `[]`.

You should use this instead.

```
operator.matches("[" + Pattern.quote("+-*/^") + "]??")
```